# Axis labels not changed in gplots.plotmeans

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, gplots

When creating a plot using `gplots.plotmeans`, the axis labels are not set to what I want, but to "means" and "Index".
Here is the code:

```
library(gplots)
plotmeans(ioe.dimension ~ ioe$profile, 
              col=3,
              xlab="Profile",  ylab="Means",
              ylim=c(2.5,6.5),
              bars=FALSE)
abline(h=4, lty=2, col=2)
```

The resulting plot is this:
[image: MeanPlot]

Comment: Could you share your data, preferably by means of `dput`? This would enable someone who wants to help you to toy around with the data and code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not get clearance from the data owner.

Answer (score 2):

This happens for some reason when `bars = FALSE`. I don't know why, but for me it works to first remove the labels with `ann = F` and then add them with a call to `title()`.

```
library(gplots)
plotmeans(ioe.dimension ~ ioe$profile, 
          col=3,
          ylim=c(2.5,6.5),
          bars=FALSE,
          ann=F)
title(xlab="Profile",  ylab="Means")
abline(h=4, lty=2, col=2)
```